# child selector in hover in scss

Tags: sass, bem

so I have this html code

```
<aside class="sidebar">
   <div class="sidebar__logo">....</div>
   ....
</aside>
```

I want the sidebar__logo width change to 80px when I hover over aside
so I write this scss style

```
.sidebar {
    width:100px;
    &__logo{
        width : 40px;
    }
    &:hover {
        width:200px;
        & .sidebar__logo {
             width: 80px;
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine, but it's not a BEM approach.

how can I change it to be something like this

```
.sidebar {
    width:100px;
    &__logo{
        width : 40px;
        & hovered over the parent {
             width : 80px
        }
    }
    &:hover {
        width:200px;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$self` to cache the current selector (&) and then access the `.sidebar__logo` with `#{$self}__logo` instead. More info: [caching current selector](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/caching-current-selector-sass/)